# if/else with undeclared variable

Tags: php

What is the proper way to do an if/else statement regarding a variable which may or may not exist?

For example: I have a website search script that gets variables from the URL. If the user has not checked any advanced options then they are not included in the URL. Basically what I'm wondering is, would it be correct to use something like the following if the variable did not exist?

```
if ($variable == "yes") { do stuff; }
```

Would this cause any sort of problems if that variable did not exist? or should I always use something like:

```
if (isset($variable) && $variable == "yes") { do stuff; }
```

Comment: option 2. always check isset if you are not sure

Comment: Agree with Kai Qing ! always check isset ! don't forget to add "else" to manage errors

Comment: what I find myself doing is something like  `$variable = isset($_REQUEST['variable']) ? $_REQUEST['variable'] : 'sensible default';`  this way all my variables are always defined, and I make sure they exist, etc..

Comment: To conclude : I would say you have to choose option 2, and have to manage errors in case $variable is not set and/or $variable is not == yes

Answer (score 2):

try to put the if value equals in the if statement, this way you never get error notice and its correct

```
if(isset($value)){
   if($value==='this'){
     //magic 
   }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion errors have to be managed by developper...even if he choose to kick them out in the bin !

Comment: just FYI there is no difference between your code and `if (isset($value) && $value == "yes)`  php interpreter will short circuit (lazy evaluate)  the isset, see it is false and never check the second condtional

Answer (score 0):

The second way imo, because it will suppress the notice error that $variable does not exist if it's not set. Either way, it's only a notice error though - so you could just suppress notices and use the first way too..

Comment: There have been arguments against error suppression - assuming you're talking about something like @$variable - for performance overhead reasons. You may be referring to setting error reporting to off

Comment: **Don't** suppress error messages unless there really is no other way. It's like sticking your fingers in your ears and singing 'I'm not listening!' whenever an error occurs.

Comment: I generally turn off notice errors because on a server that gets millions of hits per day, the logs will fill up very fast over very stupid things. If you are in production, you don't need notices - only in staging imo.

Comment: If your code is throwing millions of errors a day, maybe you should *fix your code*.

Comment: Well, if your code is throwing up notices that effect absolutely nothing, maybe nobody cares. Code isn't broken just because a notice gets thrown. That's why it's called a notice.. it's just a friendly notification, hardly a real error. Most frameworks disable notices in production mode. Most veterans aren't going to waste hours of time doing isset instead of if($variable)

Comment: @skrilled : i agree with you, sure i won't setup debug level in production ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`empty`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means `empty()` is essentially the concise equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`.

```
// $foo = 'no';

if(!empty($foo) AND $foo == 'yes')
{
    echo $foo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you check your variable for a value, check it with isset and set default values like

```
if (!isset($variable)) {
    $variable = "no";
}

if ($variable == "yes") { do stuff; }
```